# Is there a way to convert 3 separate integers to a date in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have thee separate fields in a dataset( for day, month and year). I need to convert these to a date using expression.
If it is possible, can somebody help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDate function converts the value to a date.

`=CDate("27" & "-" & "09" & "-" & "2021")`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

If it's in TSQL, you can use `DateFromParts` function.

`SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( 2021, 09, 29 )`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expression `=DateSerial(year, month, day)`